# NSDictionary initWithContentsOfFile: messes up NSDecimalNumbers, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, currency

In my iPhone app I employ `NSDecimalNumber` to store some some currency rate values.
I pull the data from the web the first time the app is launched and then again when they become obsolete, and I store them in a `NSDictionary`; then I use `writeToFile:atomically:`.

When the app is launched for the first time, my rate conversion method works allright.  Yet, when I launch the app a second time, and the rates get loaded with `-(NSDictionary*) initWithContentsOfFile:` the conversion methos stops working, and I get weird results.

I did some debug with breakpoints in the incriminated method, and I found out that the rates data are seen as `NSCFNumber`, rather than as `NSDecimalNumber`. So it appears that `initWithContentsOfFile` doesn't assign the right class to my objects. For the record, the actual value of these objects, as shown in the `description` method, corresponds to the expected rate value.

I also checked the plist file generated by `writeToFile:atomically:`, and saw that the rates are stored as `real`; I wonder whether this is the right type.

Any idea of whats going on?

Thanks in advance,
Davide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Property lists don't distinguish between decimal numbers and floating-point numbers. The `real` element holds a floating-point number. (Indeed, the serialization itself may simply be `NSNumber` sending `floatValue` to itself, unaware that the instance is actually of a subclass. That would mean the conversion to floating-point happens when you *generate* the plist data, not when you read it back in.)

You'll have to store it as a string, I think. Hopefully, that's lossless.

Comment: I've used the approach of storing NSDecimalNumbers using strings and it seems to do a good job of preserving precision.  It appears to be as close to lossless as you can get.

Answer (score 5):

Plists only work with certain data types and NSNumber is one of those. If you want the NSDecimalNumber then you have two ways to go about it. The first is to keep using plists and then convert all the NSNumbers to NSDecimalNumbers after load. The second is to switch to using NSKeyedArchiver for storing data. This requires more code but means that if you save an NSDecimalNumber, you'll get an NSDecimalNumber back.

Comment: Note that if the property-list serializer is treating the numbers as NSNumbers and asking for their floatValue *when serializing*, then you've already lost precision by that point. It's too late to get that information back.

Comment: Good point, I guess I'll follow Peter's advice and store the values as NSString.